# Multiple image upload using django restframework and postman

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

**Models.py**

```
class Image(SafeDeleteModel):

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')

class Meta:
    db_table = TABLE_PREFIX + "image"
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MultiImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class MultiImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Image.objects.all()
serializer_class = MultiImageSerializer
# parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
# permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        print(serializer.validated_data)
        serializer.save()
        custom_data = {
            "data": serializer.data
        }
        return Response(custom_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        custom_data = {
            "data": serializer.errors
        }
        return Response(custom_data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm getting an empty list when i print 'serializer.validated_data' inside view.

I use postman to invoke the api.
[image]

It returns a null value, and i'm not sure if its the right way to do it.

I removed 'many=True' from views and tries single image upload with the api, it works fine.

Someone please suggest me the simplest way to upload multiple images with the api.

Thank you for the time you spend on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, fetching the images as below solved the issue:

```
images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
```